# How to get the feed of a group with Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I tried to get a group's feed using an access token from the `Graph API Explorer` https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?pnref=story using this route
https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/feed?access_token=access_token
 and that worked perfectly; I managed to get the group's feed even though I didn't ask for any permission in the Graph API Explorer.

I tried to do the same thing but this time using the access token I get from users when they login using my application but that didn't work; an empty `data` array was returned even though the user is already a member of that group.

I searched more for that problem and some people said that I should request for the `user_groups` permission, but when I searched more I found that this permission is deprecated in the recent versions.

I searched more and I found that `user_managed_groups` would help, but the problem is that with that permission I can only get the feed of a group only if I'm an admin of that group.

**My main goal** is to get the feed of a group every time a user that is not an admin of that group but a member in it by using his access token.

### My questions

- Is there any other way to achieve my main goal?
- Did I miss anything or make something wrong when I tried accessing the groups feed using the above methods?
- Why didn't getting the group's feed using the access token I get it from my application work, but it worked when I used the access token from `Graph API Explorer`? What is the difference between an access token that comes from `Graph API Explorer` and the login API?
- Can I somehow use the access token from the Graph API Explorer and regenerate it every N minutes -for example- automatically to use it to get the feed of the group that I'm a member of instead of using other user's access tokens?

Comment: Is the group open?

Comment: @Norbert No it's close. If the group is open there will be no problem but when it's closed I can't read it's posts.